# Get random double value which is most close to another double value (but still random)

Tags: c#, random

Let say that I would like to get an **random** double value wich is:

1. greater than -0.150
2. less than +0.150
3. most close to 0.440

This number must be random...

How can I do that?

---

Additional info:

Like you said... 0.440 is not in [-0.150, 0.150], but I need to generate an number close to that number in this range...

let say that I call:

```
getMyRandomNumber(-0.150, 0.150, 0.440)
```

I would like to get an number in the range [-0.150, 0.150] but that it isn't allways 0.150

I would like to get numbers like 0.139, 0.140, 0.121,...

If I call:

```
getMyRandomNumber(-0.150, 0.150, -0.440)
```

I would like to get numbers like -0.139, -0.140, -0.121,...

Comment: "most close" compared to what? also, 0.44 is not in the [-0.15, 0.15] interval

Comment: Is this a trick question -- the value closest to .44 in that range is .15

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean exactly by "most close to 0.440"? Does that mean you choose two random values within that range and then return the larger of the two?

Comment: Do you mean something like [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)?

Comment: The random number generator will give out numbers in a certain interval, see my answer. It has no notion of "closer" to anything. Since you only change the sign of 0.44 and of the series does this mean you only care about the sign of the results? In that case just make the interval (.0, .15) or (-0.15, 0) as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Random's NextDouble()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble.aspx) returns a random number between 0.0 and 1.0

If you want to get a random number in the interval (a, b) based on the random number from NextDouble() then you need to map the (0.0, 1.0) interval you get to the (a, b) interval you need.

The simplest way is to use this formula:
`result = a + (b - a) * X` 
where `X` is the result from `NextDouble()`

If `X` is 0 then `result` will be `a`, if `X` is 1 then `result` will be `b`, for `X` between 0.0 and 1.0 the `result` will be between `a` and `b`.

If you want numbers close to a certain number (say 0.44) but no further than 0.15 away then you need to map the results into the (0.44 - 0.15, 0.44 + 0.15) interval.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random g = new Random();
double max = double.MaxValue;
double a = g.NextDouble() * max - 0.150; // greater then -0.15
double b = -g.NextDouble() * max + 0.150; // less then 0.15
```

most close is not clearly definition